# BUG: “Error: 413 The data value transmitted exceeds the capacity limit.” when calling v1/images/edits

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I’m trying to send an image from my Firebase Storage bucket to openai edit image API, but I’m getting the error above on the title.

```
exports.sendToOpenAI = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    corsMiddleware(req, res, async () => {
        if (req.method !== "POST") {
            return res.status(405).end();
        }

        try {
            const relativePath = req.body.path;
            const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

            const file = bucket.file(relativePath);
            const fileBuffer = await file.download();

            const openAIResponse = await openai.images.edit({
                image: fileBuffer[0],
                prompt: "Put a suit on that person",
                size: "256x256",
            });

            return res
                .status(200)
                .json({ success: true, response: openAIResponse.data });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error sending image to OpenAI:", error);
            return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                error: "Internal Server Error sending image to OpenAI",
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The “fileBuffer” has a length of 0.1MB and according to the API docs the image must have less than 4MB.

I tried to pass other small images too, but had no success.

I gave permissions on Firebase to anyone writes and reads the storage.

I don’t know why I’m getting this error. Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: You're not sending `fileBuffer`, you're sending `fileBuffer[0]`. What is its length?

Comment: I passed fileBuffer[0] wrong. It's supposed to be just fileBuffer. But anyway both are 0.1MB and got the same error.